# Why isn't my jobber form not loading in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the jobber api on my react website but it isn't loading

I tried changing up the code but it caused 2 forms to show up. I moved over the html that had worked in base html but now in react it doesn't want to load.

[FormRequest component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXxzs.png)
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaDyg.png)

I also put it in my html but I don't know how to hide it initially and make it load when its /form page
[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSyB4.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdWON.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.